# Getting AJAX download progress in IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

Is there any way other than `XMLHttpRequest.responseText.length` to get the current download progress of an AJAX request?

I ask this because IE just gives up with a "data not yet available" error. Other browsers have no issues, but I'd like to be able to at least give some indication of progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `progress` event’s support [is limited to version 10](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#Events) in terms of Internet Explorer, but you didn’t specify a version…

```
rq.onprogress = function(e) {
    if(e.lengthComputable) {
        progressElement.textContent = Math.floor(e.loaded / e.total * 100) + "%";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you should define separate object for IE and other browsers

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-formurlencoded');
    req.send(data);
}    // branch for IE/Windows ActiveX version

else if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
req = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
.
.
.
}
```

and you know there is more than one xmlhttp

xmlhttp1.0 , 2.0 ,...

or you can make a     try-catch block

Comment: Why? In what way does this benefit me? Besides, that would just create an `XMLHttpRequest` object in all versions of IE from the last 6 years...

Comment: ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') is an object specially for IE

Comment: Erm... that hasn't been true since 2006. Where have you been?

Comment: maybe, but IE still Working better with that.
IE Often not consistent with the changes.

Comment: Oh, so all the updates that happened in IE9 and IE10 mean nothing to you. Good to know. So what gives you the right to answer a question about IE?

Comment: The discussion is very repetitive and I don't do it again.
as I said: still better way

Comment: But ***WHY?*** You haven't told me anything about getting download progress, which is what this question is all about!